# How do I execute 10ms CPU time operation exactly 30ms interval in Windows?

Tags: windows, multithreading, visual-c++, timer

How do I execute a operation requiring around 10ms CPU time exactly 30ms interval in Windows?
(I could allow +/- 5ms margin)

I tried and already failed with Sleep API :)

For next, I thought MM Timer API. But this blog post says it can't be done.
[Why are the Multimedia Timer APIs (timeSetEvent) not as accurate as I would expect?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mediasdkstuff/archive/2009/07/02/why-are-the-multimedia-timer-apis-timesetevent-not-as-accurate-as-i-would-expect.aspx)

Also, MSDN says timeSetEvent is obsolete and we must use `CreateTimerQueueTimer` API.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757634(v=vs.85).aspx

Can `CreateTimerQueueTimer` be the solution?

Or do I need to use REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS process (I'm feeling sick)?

Comment: Well, it will be hard to do as Windows isn't a real time OS. Secondly, a Windows system timer only has a resolution of about 18ms, so there's really no way you get exactly 30ms.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: with `timeBeginPeriod` you can change that to 1ms.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes it can, but as mentioned in the first linked article about MM timers, that doesn't guarantee you get notified every millisecond.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like `CreateWaitableTimer` for this.  You can wait for it on a dedicated worker thread using `WaitForSingleObject`, a shared worker using `WaitForMultipleObjects`, or even on your UI thread by writing your main message loop to use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`.

Your 5ms precision should be achievable unless your system is badly overloaded.  Thread priorities can help, but I/O is rarely prioritized, so if you do a blocking read of a file, you can be queued behind read requests from the same disk from much lower priority threads.  Try to load any data in advance or use overlapped requests and deal with the condition that the request hasn't completed yet when your timer interval expires.

And I definitely would suggest using `timeBeginPeriod` to make all system timers more precise.

Comment: As of Windows Vista there is a concept of I/O priority, though I'm not familiar enough with it to tell whether it would help much.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Ok, but considering the *competing* program has to lower its I/O priority, the soft real-time process should still try to handle I/O latency.